# Can I access the URLs of all open websites on iPhone's mobile Safari?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios

I am thinking about creating an iPhone App and I wonder if it is possible for an app to access the URLs websites, which are opened in mobile Safari?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. Applications in iOS are sandboxed, meaning they live in their own private space. There is no official way to probe one process from the other.

A related thing is that you can register you own URI scheme, so that websites can link to yourapp:// which will fire yourapp. But that's the other way around.